# How to update a database record and still keep the old values using laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, set

In the column, I have some value like "A1, A2". Now I want to add "A3" as keep the old value as A1, A2, A3 using laravel.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Post what you have done so far. What is in your update method.

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell from what your asking is something like:

```
$model->value = $model->value . ', ' . $request->value;
```

Hope this helps. Although actual code is required from your end to give a more comprehensive answer.